# Nodelets: pure virtual method called, process died (-6)

Tags: ros, shutdown, nodelets, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the error in the question title everytime one of my Nodelet classes calls `ros::requestShutdown()`. I've tried debugging it in `gdb`, but besides the fact that the stacktrace is 5 pages (!) long, it doesn't tell me much, apart from a lot of references to `boost::shared_ptr` and `checked_delete`.

Is calling `ros::requestShutdown()` from a Nodelet unsupported or is this a bug somewhere?

Problem is the crash is causing my Nodelet destructors to not be called, which makes it hard to do proper cleanup of resources.

Breaking using `ctrl+c` does cleanly shutdown everything and calls destructors.

---

Edit: @Lorenz, you're right, I should've included more info.

System: Ubuntu Lucid (10.04.3), ROS Electric from debs.

The class that calls `ros::requestShutdown()` does so in a callback, whether that callback is called by a subscription or as a service doesn't matter.

On second thought it seems like the Bond dtor (frame 10) tries to stop/delete some timer (frame 9) which seems to try to use the `ros::TimerManager` (frame 7) which might have already been stopped/destructed.

Stacktrace:

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0xb7fe2424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb7fe2424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb785d651 in *__GI_raise (sig=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#2  0xb7860a82 in *__GI_abort () at abort.c:92
#3  0xb7aaa52f in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() ()
   from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0xb7aa8465 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0xb7aa84a2 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0xb7aa9155 in __cxa_pure_virtual () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0xb7e883fa in ros::TimerManager<ros::WallTime, ros::WallDuration, ros::WallTimerEvent>::remove(int) ()
   from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/lib/libros.so
#8  0xb7ed9779 in ros::WallTimer::Impl::stop (this=0x8076730)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-ros-comm-1.6.7/debian/ros-electric-ros-comm/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/src/libros/wall_timer.cpp:64
#9  0xb7ed9813 in ros::WallTimer::stop (this=0x806f690)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-ros-comm-1.6.7/debian/ros-electric-ros-comm/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/src/libros/wall_timer.cpp:123
#10 0xb7f30cc3 in ~Bond (this=0x806f420, __in_chrg=<value optimised out>)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-bond-core-1.6.1/debian/ros-electric-bond-core/opt/ros/electric/stacks/bond_core/bondcpp/src/bond.cpp:91
#11 0x0804f019 in checked_delete<bond::Bond> (this=0x0)
    at /usr/include/boost/checked_delete.hpp:34
#12 boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<bond::Bond>::dispose (this=0x0)
    at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_impl.hpp:78
#13 0xb7b17779 in boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release (this=0x80791d0, 
    __in_chrg=<value optimised out>)
    at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:145
#14 ~shared_count (this=0x80791d0, __in_chrg=<value optimised out>)
    at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:217
#15 ~shared_ptr (this=0x80791d0, __in_chrg=<value optimised out>)
    at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:169
#16 boost::shared_ptr<bond::Bond>::reset (this=0x80791d0, 
    __in_chrg=<value optimised out>)
    at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:386
#17 ~Nodelet (this=0x80791d0, __in_chrg=<value optimised out>)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-nodelet-core-1.6.2/debian/ros-electric-nodelet-core/opt/ros/electric/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/src/nodelet_class.cpp:48
#18 0xb2ac307d in ~SenderNodelet (this=0x80791d0, 
    __in_chrg=<value optimised out>)
    at /home/ipso/ros/stacks/nodelet_test/src/nodelets/sender_nodelet.cpp:59
#19 0xb7b1c808 in checked_delete<nodelet::Nodelet> (this=0x8076980)
    at /usr/include/boost/checked_delete.hpp:34
#20 boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<nodelet::Nodelet>::dispose (
    this=0x8076980)
    at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_impl.hpp:78
#21 0x0804e3d8 in boost::detail::sp_counted_base::release (this=0x8074180, 
    __in_chrg=<value optimised out>)
    at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_gcc_x86.hpp:145
#22 ~shared_count (this=0x8074180, __in_chrg=<value optimised out>)
    at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:217
#23 0xb7b1f820 in std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, boost::shared_ptr<nodelet::Nodelet> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, boost::shared_ptr<nodelet::Nodelet> > >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, boost::shared_ptr<nodelet::Nodelet> > > >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<std::string const, boost::shared_ptr<nodelet::Nodelet> > >*) ()
   from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/lib/libnodeletlib.so
#24 0xb7b18eed in std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, boost::shared_ptr<nodelet::Nodelet> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, boost::shared_ptr<nodelet::Nodelet> > >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, boost::shared_ptr<nodelet::Nodelet> > > >::clear (
    this=0xbffff0a4, __in_chrg=<value optimised out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_tree.h:726
#25 std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<nodelet::Nodelet>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, boost::shared_ptr<nodelet::Nodelet> > > >::clear (this=0xbffff0a4, __in_chrg=<value optimised out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_map.h:626
#26 ~Loader (this=0xbffff0a4, __in_chrg=<value optimised out>)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-nodelet-core-1.6.2/debian/ros-electric-nodelet-core/opt/ros/electric/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/src/loader.cpp:176
#27 0x0804d4e4 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbffff1c4)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-nodelet-core-1.6.2/debian/ros-electric-nodelet-core/opt/ros/electric/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/src/nodelet.cpp:277
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39983/nodelets:-pure-virtual-method-called,-process-died-(-6)/) by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-27**:
Without seeing the backtrace, it's hard to say what's going wrong. Although it might not tell you much, we might be able to infer something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nodelets are probably not supposed to call `ros::requestShutdown()`, but this is still a bug of some sort. Please [open a defect ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/newticket?component=common&type=defect&&common) with a pointer back to this question.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-27**:
Done. [ticket/4431](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4431) seems to be related.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-27**:
Yes. I knew about that ticket and the lack of a clean way for a nodelet to shut itself down. Trying `ros::requestShutdown()` was a reasonable idea, but I think it shuts down the entire nodelet manager process (and not cleanly).

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-27**:
@joq: well in my particular case I *want* to take the manager with me, but it should be done cleanly (or at least: not die in a horrible crash). Seeing the other tickets it'll probably be a while before this one is picked up.

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-27**:
Oh, I forgot: 'this one' got [ticket/5506](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5506).

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-27**:
You use case can probably be fixed, although well-behaved nodelets should probably avoid doing that, because they don't know what other nodelets are running in that manager process.